# From Swift to Objective C - updateCallDurationForVisibleCells

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to covert Speakrbox code in Objective-C.
I have already converted most of the code but I have a little problem with this one:

```
private func updateCallDurationForVisibleCells() {
    /*
        Modify all the visible cells directly, since -[UITableView reloadData] resets a lot
        of things on the table view like selection & editing states
     */
    let visibleCells = tableView.visibleCells as! [CallSummaryTableViewCell]

    guard let indexPathsForVisibleRows = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows else { return }

    for index in 0..<visibleCells.count {
        let cell = visibleCells[index]
        let indexPath = indexPathsForVisibleRows[index]

        guard let call = call(at: indexPath) else { return }
        cell.durationLabel?.text = durationLabelText(forCall: call)
    }
}
```

I tried to convert it, and here is what I have:

```
-(void) updateCallDurationForVisibleCells :(id)sender {
    /*
     Modify all the visible cells directly, since -[UITableView reloadData] resets a lot
     of things on the table view like selection & editing states
     */

    _visibleCells = _tableview.visibleCells;

    if(_indexPathsForVisibleRows == _tableview.indexPathsForVisibleRows) { return ; }
    int index;
    for (index=0; index<_visibleCells.count; index ++)
    {
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = _visibleCells[index];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = _indexPathsForVisibleRows[index];
        UITableViewCell* call;

        if((call = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]))
          { return ; }

    }
}
```

Could any one please help me to convert this Swift code into Objective-C? The code doesn't compile for the reason that I didn't know how to convert this line of code:

```
cell.durationLabel?.text = durationLabelText(forCall: call)
```

Also, I don't know if I did it in the right way, especially the conversion of `guard let`.

you will find here Call and durationLabelText functions that I have used in pdateCallDurationForVisibleCells function:

```
  private func call(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> SpeakerboxCall? {
    return callManager?.calls[indexPath.row]
}//swift


private func durationLabelText(forCall call: SpeakerboxCall) -> String? {
    return call.hasConnected ? callDurationFormatter.format(timeInterval: call.duration) : nil
}//Swift
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clearly explain what issue you are having with the code you posted.

Comment: You didn't understand how works `guard let`: `if(_indexPathsForVisibleRows == _tableview.indexPathsForVisibleRows) { return ; }`=> `if (!_tableview.indexPathsForVisibleRows){return;}` For `guard let call = call(at: indexPath) else { return }`, I don't know what's `call`.

Comment: @Rmaddy i'm trying to convert a swift method to objective c , the first code is in swift and the second one is an objectiveC code that i have implemented it to have the same results than the swift one

Comment: What is the problem you're facing after conversion?

Comment: I know what you are trying to do. But you need to explain what issue you are actually having with your code conversion. Does it compile? Are there errors? Does it simply not work as expected? Be clear and specific about your issue.

Comment: @rmaddy no it doesn't compile because i didn't know how to convert this line of code  :                                                                   cell.durationLabel?.text = durationLabelText(forCall: call) also i don'y know if i did it in the right way specially the conversion of guard let

Comment: As I said, please [edit] your question with these clarifications. Posting them in comments makes them hard to find by other viewers of your question.

Comment: @AdilSoomro i can't covert the last line of code : cell.durationLabel?.text = durationLabelText(forCall: call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fixed up version of your Objective-C code. Please note that when you see `var` or `let` in Swift, you are creating a local variable. Do not create a bunch a needless instance variables or properties in the Objective-C code when you should just use local variables.

```
- (void)updateCallDurationForVisibleCells {
    /*
     Modify all the visible cells directly, since -[UITableView reloadData] resets a lot
     of things on the table view like selection & editing states
     */

    NSArray *indexPathsForVisibleRows = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows;
    if(!indexPathsForVisibleRows) { return ; }

    NSArray *visibleCells = self.tableview.visibleCells;

    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < _visibleCells.count; index++) {
        CallSummaryTableViewCell *cell = visibleCells[index];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = indexPathsForVisibleRows[index];

        SomeDataType *call = [self call:indexPath];
        if (!call) { return; }

        cell.durationLabel.text = [self durationLabelText:call];
    }
}
```

There is some information missing which means this conversion may not be 100% correct.

1. You haven't shown the Objective-C signature of the `call:` method so I can't be sure how to call it properly and I don't know what data type to use for the `call` variable. Replace `SomeDataType` with the proper type.
2. You haven't shown the Objective-C signature of the `durationLabelText:` method so I can't be 100% sure about the proper way to call it.

If you post those details in your question I can be sure this answer is updated properly.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have modified the question and u have added the durationLabelText: and call: methods

Comment: You need to add the Objective-C, not Swift, version of those methods.

Comment: I'm trying to convert them that's why I have added swift version

Comment: You need to post your attempt to convert them. We are here to help you fix your efforts, not do the whole conversion for you.

Comment: I'm not asking for conversion I'm trying to do it by my self because that's my work, I just posted them in Swift to let another know how these methods work that's all

Comment: OK, but for us to know how to update our answers, we need to know the Objective-C signatures of your `durationLabelText:` and `call:` methods. That is why I asked you to post the Objective-C version of those methods.

Comment: i will post them as soon as possible, I'm working on the already

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Thanks to users like @rmaddy, newbies like me get to learn how to write answers.Adding the final full code part.

Skip to the final part of the answer to get the working code.
In case you want to know where you went wrong, read the full answer.

There are multiple things that are possibly not right here, let me address what I know:

1. The guard statement is used for graceful exit. I'm no Java expert, but consider this to be like Exceptions in JAVA. The Obj-C code for your first guard would be:

   ```
   if (nil == _tableview.indexPathsForVisibleRows){
      return
   }
   ```

   This also means that there's no necessity for the _indexPathsForVisibleRows variable.

   I'd recommend this article to understand guard better:
   https://ericcerney.com/swift-guard-statement/
2. With respect to your second guard, please pay attention to detail.
   **call**(at: indexPath) is not the same as **cellForRowAtIndexPath**.
   **call**(at: indexPath) is a class function that returns a datatype, say CallType. **cellForRowAtIndexPath** is a UITableView function, that returns a cell.
3. The cell in the below line is more likely to be of type CallSummaryTableViewCell

   ```
   UICollectionViewCell *cell = _visibleCells[index];
   ```
4. Regarding durationLabelText(), it seems to be a class function in the swift file whose declaration would be something like:

   ```
   //Assume the type of "call" is CallType
   private func durationLabelText(forCall call : CallType) -> String{
   //your code here  
   }
   ```

   The Objective-C equivalent would be:

   ```
   -(NSString*) durationLabelTextForCall: (id<CallType>) call{
   //your code here
   }
   ```

   The Objective-C call would be:

   ```
   cell.durationLabel.text = [self durationLabelTextForCall: call]
   ```

So, the final code would be like this:

```
-(NSString*) durationLabelTextForCall: (id<CallType>) call{
//your code here
}

-(id<CallType>) callAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath) indexPath{
//your code here
}

- (void)updateCallDurationForVisibleCells {
    /*
     Modify all the visible cells directly, since -[UITableView reloadData] resets a lot
     of things on the table view like selection & editing states
     */
    if (nil == _tableview.indexPathsForVisibleRows){
        return
    }

    NSArray *visibleCells = self.tableview.visibleCells;

    for (index=0; index<visibleCells.count; index ++)
    {
        CallSummaryTableViewCell *cell = visibleCells[index];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = _tableview.indexPathsForVisibleRows[index];

        id<CallType> call = [self callAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (nil == call){
            return
        }
        cell.durationLabel.text = [self durationLabelTextForCall: call]    
   }
}
```

Comment: You mention Java in your answer but the question is about Swift and Objective-C.

Comment: Hi @rmaddy, I wanted to show the JAVA Exception as an analogy to guard. I guess I can also say Asserts in Swift, but not very strong in that either.. I'll edit my answer to say "Exceptions in JAVA"